# Facebook Like Button Shows in Firefox but not IE - JS errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, firefox, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button and it is working in Firefox but on IE I am getting javascript errors and the button is not showing up:

http://www.bluevoice.org/webfilms_killingattaiji.php

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Not sure what I need to correct in the code. I used the html5 code generated on FB and have the app all set up.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't show in Chrome for me. Are you sure there aren't other errors causing this?

Comment: I have no idea what is causing it. I guess the only place it is working is Firefox. It works for me on the very first load in IE. If I refresh the page I get errors. If I close the browser and start again, it shows the first time and then its gone.

Comment: Errors I am getting:

Message: 'root' is null or not an object
Line: 6
Char: 1252
Code: 0
URI: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 36
Char: 375
Code: 0
URI: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 93
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.bluevoice.org/webfilms_killingattaiji.php

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is because your html tag is wrong -- IE can't handle custom elements (e.g., "`<fb:like>`") without an html namespace. You've got them defined, but I'm wondering if all the extra elements are confusing IE.

Try:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```